# Upgrade Redis cluster Ubuntu

Tags: redis-cluster

I have installed redis cluster 3.0.0. But Want to upgrade it to 3.0.7. Can somebody tell me the steps to do it?

I don't want to loose any data. And don't want any downtime either.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I did when upgrading from 2.9.101 to 3.0 release. I hope it will do for upgrading to 3.0.7 too.

- Compile 3.0.7 from the source and start several instances with cluster enabled.
- Let the 3.0.7 instances replicate the 3.0.0 instances as slave
- Connect to each 3.0.7 instance and do a manual [failover](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-failover), then the 3.0.0 masters would become slaves after several seconds.
- Wait for your application to connect to the new masters; also check the configuration files, and modify the entries to the new masters on your need
- Remove those slaves

**UPDATE : Docker approach**

As it's probably unable to replacing the binary executable while the process is still alive, you could do it by run some Redis in [docker](http://docker.io/).

First you should install docker on your machine and pull the Redis image, or pull a basic OS image and manually build Redis in it, whatever

Based on this image, you are supposed to

- copy your current `redis.conf` into it
- make sure the `dir` exists in the image (`cluster-config-file` could be the same for all the containers as they are saved individually in their own fs)
- make sure the directory for `logfile` exists and is **not** the same as `dir` (we will later map this directory to the host)
- leave `port` `logfile` anything you like, as they are specified when a container is started
- commit the image as `redis-3.0.7`

Now launch a containerized Redis. I suppose your `logfile` is located in `/var/log/redis/`, this Redis binds `:8000`, and your config file in the image is `/etc/redis/redis.conf`

```
docker run -d --net=host -v /var/log/redis:/var/log/redis \
        -p 8000:8000 -t redis-3.0.7 \
    /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf \
        --port 8000 \
        --logfile /var/log/redis/redis_8000.log
```

Now you have a Redis 3.0.7 instance, and are ready to finish the rest steps in the previous part.

Comment: I have just 2 cores in the machine. Adding another redis in the same machine would work ?

Comment: @Ish The replications don't use much CPU loads and you could replace them one by one. But I'm afraid it is a problem that you replace the redis-server executable while the 3.0 instances are still serving. I did that in separated machines.

Comment: I would like to do in the same machines.

Comment: @lsh Updated my answer. I'm afraid this is a little sophisticated as basic knowledge about docker is needed. Anyway it is workable (at least for me, I don't know if anyone else run Redis in docker containers). Hope this could help.